# How to calculate work done for phase change?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, work, phase-transition

During phase change, latent heat is responsible for change in internal change and also for work done by or on system as it's volume increases or decreases. But how do we calculate the work done by system. For example:

When 1 g of water at 0°C and 10^5 N/m² pressure is converted into ice of volume 1.091 cm³, find the work done by water?

In this question most of the answers have used formula external pressure times change in volume(W=P∆V) which is used for irreversible process but freezing is not irreversible.
Don't we need to use internal pressure or something like that instead of external pressure?
Are both internal and external pressure equal in this case?

Comment: The external and internal pressures are equal, 1 Bar.  The pressure the atmosphere exerts on the water is equal to the oressure the water exerts on the atmosphere.

Comment: So internal pressure remains constant in entire process?

Comment: Of course.  What would make you think otherwise?